# Prevent Concurrently Selecting Same Row Value From SQL Server Table in EF

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-6, locking

I have a table like this. Where row number will be incremented by 1 (Not using Identity). The incrementation is done by selecting a max value of particular category. for ex: if I want to add a product of category veggies. I will get the max of that category and add + 1 to it. max value of veggies here is 1 so next row number will be 2.

This is where problem arises. If two user tries to add a veggies product. They will get same row number. This is an example structure of table.
I cannot use unique key for column Row Number because it is not data specific. it is specific to the category. Each individual category row number will start from 1,2...
Used the concurrency check attribute and Row Version but not helped.

| RowNumber | Product Name | Category | User |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mouse | e-item | user1 |
| 1 | bean | veggies | user1 |
| 1 | pencil | stationery | user2 |
| 2 | onion | veggies | user1 |
| 2 | Tomato | veggies | user2 |

I am using EF and C# for this application
Does anyone faced this issue? Kindly give me a suggestion.

Comment: Usually better to just use an identity column and then *compute* `RowNumber` via `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY IdentityColumnYouDecidedNotToUse)`. If necessary, you can persist those values as a *separate* `UPDATE` issued after the `INSERT`.

Comment: Use a sequence when making your new category? Put categories in a separate table with an autoincrement PK and a unqiue index on name?

Comment: You shouldn't do it that way. But if you have to, you have to ensure you lock the table for single use while allocating. There are loads of example of how to do that out there.

Comment: You're reinventing the wheel. Just us a `ROW_NUMBER`